# Partition Key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

If in my cassandra CF, RowKey is (a, b, c) and my data is highly skewed with cardinality of a being let's say just one. Will entire data reside on single node of my cassandra cluster if my replication factor is 1?

Also, If that node is down, What exception will i get?

Comment: What do you mean by row key. You mean the primary key? It might be clearer to post the CQL DDL for the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have one partition key and RF 1 you will not be able to access your data if the node that the row hashes to is down. You will get an Unavailable Exception.

http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/UnavailableException.html

`Primary Key ((a),b,c)` or `Primary Key (a,b,c)` Means that only `a` decides which node the data resides on.

`Primary Key ((a,b),c)` Would mean that you are using a composite key and the combination of `a` and `b` deterimines where the node is.

`Primary key ((a,b,c))` Means that the full combination of `a`, `b`, and `c` is used to decide the correct node.

All of the variables not in the first set of inner parenthesis act as clustering keys and determine the sorted order of data *within* a row but not which node the row is placed on.

Comment: Thanks RussS for the answer. In this case, will entire data reside on one node? Won't 'b' and 'c' of row key play any role in deciding which node data goes to?

Comment: Updated answer. Only parts of the composite partition key would effect node placement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your schema. The solution will be clear if you post your CQL DDL and cassandra.yaml configurations that are related to your question. By assumption, if your cluster is having 4 nodes (node A,B,C,D) with replication factor of 1, having partitioner as any random partitioner and your schema is some think like below you may refer the answer.

```
CREATE TABLE demotable(
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text,
    PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c)
);
```

In the above schema, the partition key is **`a`**, the clustering key is **`b`**. For every insert, the partition key will determine where the row to be insert. Let us assume, Node A is holding the partition key range of 0-25, node B is holding the partition key range of 26-50, node C is holding the partition key range of 51-75, node D is holding the partition key range of >76. Consider the the following insert statements,

```
insert into demotable (a,b,c,d) values ('value1','value100','value101','value102','value103');
insert into demotable (a,b,c,d) values ('value1','value200','value201','value202','value203');
insert into demotable (a,b,c,d) values ('value1','value300','value301','value302','value303');
insert into demotable (a,b,c,d) values ('value2','value400','value401','value402','value403');
```

First three query has a partition key as **`value1`** and fourth query has a partition key as **`value2`**. If the hash value for **`value1`** is 12 (just for example), these three rows will goes to the **`Node A`**. If the hash value for **`value2`** is 29 (just for example), this row will goes to the **`Node B`**.

**`If that node is down, What exception will i get?`**

Let us consider if the node A is down and rest of the node is up.

`select * from demotable where a='value1'` will wont work, you will get **`Unavailable Exception`**

But, `select * from demotable where a='value2'` will work since it resides on Node B.

Unfortunately, `select * from demotable` will also wont work. since there might have a chance to have some records in the Node A. So the select all query will wont work if any one of the node is down with a replication of 1.